# How to add my current location with osmdroid?

Tags: android, location, openstreetmap, point, osmdroid

I'm completely new in Android studio and I want to build a project which shows the x,y coordinates of a user in the openstreet map (as a pointer). I viewed the GitHub codes, but it really was a struggle..

I added the map, can you please explain me how can I get my location from gps?
Here's my code..

```
package mytestapplication.hello.com.map;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.IMyLocationConsumer;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.IMyLocationProvider;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.MyLocationNewOverlay;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MapView map = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));

        map = findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        mapController.setZoom((long) 14);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(x, y);
        mapController.animateTo(startPoint);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        map.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        map.onResume();
    }


}
```

Any answer would be completely helpful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [osmdroid wiki](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/). The simplest solution is to add a [My Location overlay](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library#how-to-add-the-my-location-overlay) to your map view:

```
this.mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(context),mMapView);
this.mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mLocationOverlay);
```

Comment: is it easier to follow the osmbonuspack? :) I readed that it has tools for navigation and points :D

Comment: and, when I put this code it cannot resolve the mMapView, mLocationOverlay, LocationOverlay, context...

Comment: You need to adapt the code to match your variable names. In your case, `mMapView` is called `map`, `context` is called `ctx`, `mLocationOverlay` needs to be created as a class member similar to `map`.

Comment: where should these lines will be write? I mean, in which method?

Comment: This depends on your code. How about in `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 2):

If found this code and it gave me results immediately:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location lastKnownLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (lastKnownLoc != null) {
        int longitude = (int) (lastKnownLoc.getLongitude() * 1000000);
        int latitude = (int) (lastKnownLoc.getLatitude() * 1000000);
        GeoPoint location = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
    }
```

Problem with `myLocationNewOverlay.getMyLocation`: it waits to begin with the locations calculation until other processes are finished (at least for me it seemed like that).